# Are there any good methods to explore Python data type?

Tags: python, function, types, dataframe

Suppose I have a python dataframe in which columns are of different types (e.g. integer, numeric, string etc.).

```
Dataframe:

Date        Var1    Var2  Var3      Var4    ......... VarN

2015-01-01   2      7.1   New York  xyz@gmail.com     Male
2015-01-02   13     9.3   New Delhi zyx@gmail.com     Female
```

Is there any function in python (such as dtype) which we can use to have an idea about structure of the dataframe (something similar to str() in R ).

Alternative, can we write a function to get more info about dataframe?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [DataFrame.dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]:
  action  id                      ts
0      B   3 2016-01-28 06:14:08.249
1      A   3 2016-01-28 07:08:49.901
2      A   4 2016-01-28 10:42:27.228
3      B   4 2016-01-29 04:15:33.724
4      B   4 2016-01-29 04:20:33.724
5      B   5 2016-01-28 11:12:51.892

In [91]: df.dtypes
Out[91]:
action            object
id                 int64
ts        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU. It worked for other DFs but did not work on JSON types DFs (e.g. the one which I fetched data from twitter API....)  " search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q = query, count = HowManyTweets) "

Comment: @AadhyaManuAnand, what is the data frame from your question - is it pandas data frame or something different?